# Error 500 (Internal Server Error) con PHP AJAX | Formulario de contacto

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, contact-form-7

He creado un *formulario de contacto* y cada vez que le doy a enviar con todos los *campos rellenados*, aparece el *siguiente error*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" id="form-name" name="form-name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
<input type="email" id="form-email" name="form-email" placeholder="Email" required>
<textarea id="form-message" name="form-message" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="contact-btn" class="contact-btn btn">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**JQUERY | AJAX**

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#contact-form');
    var formMessages = $('#error-text');

    $(form).submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'include/php/contact.php',
            data: formData
        }).done(function(response) {
            $(formMessages).text(response);
            $('#error-alert').removeClass('closed');
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#error-alert').addClass('closed'); },5000);

            $('#form-name').val('');
            $('#form-email').val('');
            $('#form-message').val('');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            $(formMessages).text(response);
            $('#error-alert').removeClass('closed');
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#error-alert').addClass('closed'); },5000);

            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('<p>Oops! Ocurrió un error y tu mensaje no pudo ser enviado...</p>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["form-name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["form-email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["form-message"]);

    if (empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "<p>Oops! Hubo un problema con tu envío. Por favor, completa el formulario e inténtalo otra vez...</p>";
        exit;
    }

    $recipient = "info@antoniobuenog.com";
    $subject = "Nuevo mensaje de $name";

    $email_content = "Nombre: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Mensaje:\n$message\n";

    $email_headers = "De: $name <$email>";

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "<p>¡Gracias! Tu mensaje ha sido enviado</p>";
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "<p>Oops! Hubo un problema y no pudimos enviar tu mensaje. Por favor, inténtalo más tarde...</p>";
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "<p>Hubo un problema con tu envío. Por favor, inténtalo otra vez...</p>";
}
?>
```

Dice que la variable `response` no está definida...

*Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la pregunta es por que sucede el error en tu código Javascript `Uncaught: ReferenceError: response is not defined` es debido a que dentro de la función callback `.fail` *response* no existe dentro del ámbito de la función, bastaria con que reemplaces *response* con *data*.

`...
}).fail(function(data) {
    $(formMessages).text(data);
    $('#error-alert').removeClass('closed');
...`

Ahora si la pregunta es por que el tu código PHP retorna un error 500 deberías revisar si PHP puede enviar correos, posiblemente debido a que no este bien configurado. Ademas cambia la siguiente linea:

`$email_headers = "De: $name <$email>";`

Por:

`$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";`

debido a que los encabezados deben ser palabras en ingles.

Espero te sea de ayuda.